# I seem to be having trouble with basic if/else statements :/

Tags: c++, output

**THE IDEA (C++):**

The idea is simple, if you're under 21 and in full time education, you're eligible (no idea for what, it's just homework). If you're not eligible, you have to tell the user why.

```
int main()
{
    string education;
    int age;

    cout << "Are you in full time education? (y/n): ";
    cin >> education;

    cout << "\nEnter your age: ";
    cin >> age;
    system("cls");

    if (((education == "yes" || education == "y")) && (age <= 21))
    {
        cout << "You are eligible.";
    }
    else if (((education == "yes" || "y")) && (age > 21))
    {
        cout << "You are not eligible because you are over 21.";
    }
    else if (((education == "no" || "n")) && (age <= 21))
    {
        cout << "You are not eligible because you are not in full time education.";
    }
    else if (((education == "no" || "n")) && (age > 21))
    {
        cout << "You are not eligible because you are not in full time education and you are over 21.";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "There is a problem with your input.";
    }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

Now, if I input that I'm NOT in fulltime education AND over 21, the output is "You are not eligible because you are over 21.", which is technically true, but it should be giving me "You are not eligible because you are not in full time education and you are over 21." instead!

*Things to note:*

- My #include statements are cut out of the screenshot, but don't worry about them, I know they're fine.
- All the "else if" statements were originally just "if", but I made them this way to try and fix the issue.. to no avail clearly.

Comment: do not post images of code, copy and paste it in the question

Comment: Images of code are not acceptable here. Please see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons why. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post and formatted for readability. While you're making the [edit] to provide the code instead, you can also more clearly explain the problem you're having and ask a **specific question** related to the code, so we can try to help. You may want to spend a few minutes taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: noted. @Berto99

Comment: Please do not cut the includes, make a [mre] instead. It is not about them being OK or not, it is about me not having to type them in if I want to reproduce your problem. Please fix this and everything else missing for an MRE. The question is currently closed because of that and hence prevents me from adding another answer which explains the behaviour you observe, in addition to the existing answer which only gives the wrong line and how to fix it. (@Berto99, alternatively you add the explanation of how the error causes the observed behaviour to your answer, it might get you more upvotes.)

Answer (score 5):

You can't use the or operator like this

```
a == 'first' || 'second' // education == 'yes' || 'y'
```

in order to say "if `a` is equal to `first` or `second`", you have to repeat the `a==` also on the right hand side:

```
a == 'first' || a == 'second' // education == 'yes' || education == 'y'
```